# Recover data from a hard drive (Let's get geeky)

Tags: external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

Hello there all you level 80 techies

I have a drive which I want to do a raw copy of the data onto an image file.
But the drive is inaccessible.
 A few details :

- drive : seems to be a WD passport drive with integrated USB 3.0 port
  ( It doesn't have the cover) WD500MBVW - 11AMCS2 Windows can see the
  drive is there but it refuses to initialize it on compmgmt though it takes a while for windows to acknowledge there is *something* connected
- Bios just freezes while the drive is connected during boot
- Checkdisk and diskpart are no help.
- Drive "recovery" software is useless at this point since they rely on
  the drive being initialized.
- Partedmagic from Hiren's boot doesn't see the drive either (I should
  probably try again but wait a bit)
- [MHDD](http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/) can only see drives connected via SATA and I'm not high
  level enough in techskill to be able to add USB drivers for MHDD to
  see USB HDD's.

Assuming the PCB isn't burnt or the heads/Platter aren't broken/misaligned
I'm looking for suggestions on what can I try to make the drive accessible.Perhaps a new approach. Please, contribute onto the geekdom.
This is more of a stubbornness project than need. I know tech companies do this stuff for $.

Comment: Can you remove the HDD and connect it directly with SATA?

Comment: I wish. It is one of those with integrated USB connectors soddered into the board. https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/Lr4AAOSwmZFZn~k9/s-l300.jpg

Comment: The computer refusing to POST while the drive is connected signals a short in the USB circuitry to me. You should be able to buy a replacement controller board. That will probably give you access to the drive again... if not the data. From there data recovery software should handle the rest. Just make sure you get _exactly_ the same board.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong It also may just be the connectors - mini/micro USB connectors are finicky and don't survive well under constant connect/disconnect cycles. Also may be some solder whiskers somewhere on the PCB or some metal dust. Maybe clean with a q-tip and rubbing alcohol if the PCB has been exposed to the elements

Comment: All good suggestions! replacing the pcb is a little out of my interest(though it is feasible) currently, but I'll certainly have a look at the circuits with a magnifying glass and see If the contacts look alright.